# pandas: DataFrame.mean() very slow. How can I calculate means of columns faster?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a rather large CSV file, it contains 9917530 rows (without the header), and 54 columns. Columns are real or integer, only one contains dates. There is a few NULL values on the file, which are translated to `nan` after I load it to pandas `DataFrame`, which I do like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

After loading, which I think was very fast, cause it took around 30 seconds (pretty much the same time as counting lines with the Unix tool `wc`), the process was taking around 4Gb of RAM (the size of of the file on disk: 2.2 Gb. So far so good.

Then I tried to do the following:

```
column_means = data.mean()
```

The process' occupied memory grew to ~22Gb very quickly. I could also see the processor (one core) was very very busy - for like three hours, after that I killed the process, cause I needed to use the machine for other things. I have a pretty fast PC with Linux - it has 2 processors, each having 4 cores, so it's 8 cores all together, and 32 Gb of RAM. I cannot believe calculating column means should take so long.

Can anybody explain why `DataFrame.mean()` is so slow? And more importantly, what is a better way of calculating means of columns of a file like that? Did I not load the file the best way possible, should I use a different function instead of `DataFrame.mean()` or perhaps a completely different tool?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT. Here is what `df.info()` shows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9917530 entries, 0 to 9917529
Data columns (total 54 columns):
srch_id                        9917530  non-null values
date_time                      9917530  non-null values
site_id                        9917530  non-null values
visitor_location_country_id    9917530  non-null values
visitor_hist_starrating        505297  non-null values
visitor_hist_adr_usd           507612  non-null values
prop_country_id                9917530  non-null values
prop_id                        9917530  non-null values
prop_starrating                9917530  non-null values
prop_review_score              9902900  non-null values
prop_brand_bool                9917530  non-null values
prop_location_score1           9917530  non-null values
prop_location_score2           7739150  non-null values
prop_log_historical_price      9917530  non-null values
position                       9917530  non-null values
price_usd                      9917530  non-null values
promotion_flag                 9917530  non-null values
srch_destination_id            9917530  non-null values
srch_length_of_stay            9917530  non-null values
srch_booking_window            9917530  non-null values
srch_adults_count              9917530  non-null values
srch_children_count            9917530  non-null values
srch_room_count                9917530  non-null values
srch_saturday_night_bool       9917530  non-null values
srch_query_affinity_score      635564  non-null values
orig_destination_distance      6701069  non-null values
random_bool                    9917530  non-null values
comp1_rate                     235806  non-null values
comp1_inv                      254433  non-null values
comp1_rate_percent_diff        184907  non-null values
comp2_rate                     4040633  non-null values
comp2_inv                      4251538  non-null values
comp2_rate_percent_diff        1109847  non-null values
comp3_rate                     3059273  non-null values
comp3_inv                      3292221  non-null values
comp3_rate_percent_diff        944007  non-null values
comp4_rate                     620099  non-null values
comp4_inv                      692471  non-null values
comp4_rate_percent_diff        264213  non-null values
comp5_rate                     4444294  non-null values
comp5_inv                      4720833  non-null values
comp5_rate_percent_diff        1681006  non-null values
comp6_rate                     482487  non-null values
comp6_inv                      524145  non-null values
comp6_rate_percent_diff        193312  non-null values
comp7_rate                     631077  non-null values
comp7_inv                      713175  non-null values
comp7_rate_percent_diff        277838  non-null values
comp8_rate                     3819043  non-null values
comp8_inv                      3960388  non-null values
comp8_rate_percent_diff        1225707  non-null values
click_bool                     9917530  non-null values
gross_bookings_usd             276592  non-null values
booking_bool                   9917530  non-null values
dtypes: float64(34), int64(19), object(1)None
```

Comment: your dtypes are problably not defined correctly, show ``df.info()``. ``object`` are should only be on string-likes (and not on numerics)

Comment: @Jeff thanks, I added output of `df.info()` to the question. I don't quite understand what you mean by 'should only be on string-likes (and not on numerics)', can you explain, please?

Comment: what version pandas/numpy?

Comment: I believe they are the latest stable versions available. I'm going to check your solution now, sounds very promising!..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a similar sized from , but without an object column

```
In [10]: nrows = 10000000

In [11]: df = pd.concat([DataFrame(randn(int(nrows),34),columns=[ 'f%s' % i for i in range(34) ]),DataFrame(randint(0,10,size=int(nrows*19)).reshape(int(nrows),19),columns=[ 'i%s' % i for i in range(19) ])],axis=1)

In [12]: df.iloc[1000:10000,0:20] = np.nan

In [13]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 53 columns):
f0     9991000  non-null values
f1     9991000  non-null values
f2     9991000  non-null values
f3     9991000  non-null values
f4     9991000  non-null values
f5     9991000  non-null values
f6     9991000  non-null values
f7     9991000  non-null values
f8     9991000  non-null values
f9     9991000  non-null values
f10    9991000  non-null values
f11    9991000  non-null values
f12    9991000  non-null values
f13    9991000  non-null values
f14    9991000  non-null values
f15    9991000  non-null values
f16    9991000  non-null values
f17    9991000  non-null values
f18    9991000  non-null values
f19    9991000  non-null values
f20    10000000  non-null values
f21    10000000  non-null values
f22    10000000  non-null values
f23    10000000  non-null values
f24    10000000  non-null values
f25    10000000  non-null values
f26    10000000  non-null values
f27    10000000  non-null values
f28    10000000  non-null values
f29    10000000  non-null values
f30    10000000  non-null values
f31    10000000  non-null values
f32    10000000  non-null values
f33    10000000  non-null values
i0     10000000  non-null values
i1     10000000  non-null values
i2     10000000  non-null values
i3     10000000  non-null values
i4     10000000  non-null values
i5     10000000  non-null values
i6     10000000  non-null values
i7     10000000  non-null values
i8     10000000  non-null values
i9     10000000  non-null values
i10    10000000  non-null values
i11    10000000  non-null values
i12    10000000  non-null values
i13    10000000  non-null values
i14    10000000  non-null values
i15    10000000  non-null values
i16    10000000  non-null values
i17    10000000  non-null values
i18    10000000  non-null values
dtypes: float64(34), int64(19)
```

Timings (similar machine specs to you)

```
In [14]: %timeit df.mean()
1 loops, best of 3: 21.5 s per loop
```

You can get a 2x speedup by pre-converting to floats (mean does this, but does it in a more general way, so slower)

```
In [15]: %timeit df.astype('float64').mean()
1 loops, best of 3: 9.45 s per loop
```

You problem is the object column. Mean will try to calculate for all of the columns, but because of the object column everything is upcast to `object` dtype which is not efficient for calculating.

Best bet is to do

```
 df._get_numeric_data().mean()
```

There is an option to do this `numeric_only`, at the lower level, but for some reason we don't directly support this via the top-level functions (e.g. mean). I think will create an issue to add this parameter. However will prob be `False` by default (to not-exclude).

Comment: Fantastic! Getting rid of my `date_time` column, which was loaded to pandas as dtype object did the trick! Now computing means is really fast, as it should be. Thank you so much, Jeff!

Comment: check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#specifying-date-columns) for putting the datetime in proper dtype.

Comment: @Jeff Your link seems outdated, [this one](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#specifying-date-columns) seems to link to the proper section.
And to understand the way pandas works better: if date-columns are parsed _correcly_ (meaning to type `DatetimeIndex`), there should be no considerable perf-loss as it is the case with columns of type `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this -

pd.DataFrame(data.describe())

I noticed this was faster than the case where I was using mean on a dataframe