# Python Find the Mean using Panda Library

Tags: python, pandas

I just starting learning python, and we were given this task to perform data exploration on kddcup.data_10_percent dataset (some of you might know this)

I decided to use Panda find the various min, max, std.dev etc etc. However, the execution of df.mean() , the kernel took more than an hour and still loading. Any advice would help, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: DataFrame.mean() very slow. How can I calculate means of columns faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701569/pandas-dataframe-mean-very-slow-how-can-i-calculate-means-of-columns-faster)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) to get descriptive statistics including those that summarize the central tendency, dispersion and shape of a dataset, excluding NaN values.

Time for `df.mean()` also depends upon the size of your dataset. You might wanna get `df['name_of_column'].mean()` which is mean of a column in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

df.mean() tends to work slow, there is an option at the lower level where we can calculate the mean only for the numeric data present in the dataset by specifying numeric_only=True.

Try using **df.mean(numeric_only=True)**, this will be faster.

-https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Let me know if this helps !