# Calculating mean of a dataframe takes way longer than the standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a very large pandas Dataframe for which I am trying to find the std and mean. The It takes only few seconds to calculate the std while finding the mean takes in the order of minutes. Am I missing something or we have to calculate the mean first to calculate the standard deviation? How come calculating the mean takes much more time?

```
df = pd.read_csv('large_df.csv')
std = df.std()
mean = df.mean()
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18701569/11246056

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: DataFrame.mean() very slow. How can I calculate means of columns faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701569/pandas-dataframe-mean-very-slow-how-can-i-calculate-means-of-columns-faster)